# Unlimited timing interval in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one span, and I wrote code for bouncing element, but I can only to set interval for bouncing, but how to set unlimited/infinitely bouncing.

HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="rect">!!!</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rect').effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RGvjj/164/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set success callback function in **[`effect()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/effect/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cmp = function () {
        $('.rect').effect("bounce", {
            times: 3
        }, 300, cmp);
    }
    cmp();
})
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/RGvjj/167/)**

Comment: @RS92 : glad to help you :)

Comment: Do you have a skype, to ask you sometimes, that's will be great help for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can Bounce element through CSS3 infinity time

```css
.bounce {
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  bottom:0;
  margin-top:-25px;
  margin-left:-25px;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%       { bottom:5px; }
  25%, 75% { bottom:15px; }
  50%      { bottom:20px; }
  100%     {bottom:0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="bounce"></div>
```

if you want to get more better Example but it's have very large code see below code:

```css
body { background-color: #DDDDDD; font: 30px sans-serif; height: 350px;}


.ball-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 120px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: -60px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%;
}

.ball {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%,rgba(119,119,119,1) 99%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%,rgba(119,119,119,1) 99%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(187,187,187,1) 0%,rgba(119,119,119,1) 99%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.4), inset -2px -1px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0 0 1px #000;
    -webkit-animation: jump 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: jump 1s infinite;
    animation: jump 1s infinite;
}

.ball::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 40px / 20px;
    left: 30px;
    top: 10px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(232,232,232,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(232,232,232,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(232,232,232,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}

.ball-shadow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 65px;
    border-radius: 30px / 40px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0 20px 35px rgba(20,20,20,.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.3);
    transform: scaleY(0.3);
    -webkit-animation: shrink 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: shrink 1s infinite;
    animation: shrink 1s infinite;
}

/**
 * animation
 */

@-webkit-keyframes jump {
    0% {
 top: 0;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    40% {}
    50% {
 top: 140px;
 height: 120px;
 -webkit-animtion-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    55% {
 top: 160px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 70px/60px;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    65% {
 top: 110px;
 height: 120px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    95% {
 top: 0;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    100% {
 top: 0;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes jump {
    0% {
 top: 0;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    40% {}
    50% {
 top: 140px;
 height: 120px;
 -moz-animtion-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    55% {
 top: 160px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 70px/60px;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    65% {
 top: 110px;
 height: 120px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    95% {
 top: 0;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    100% {
 top: 0;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
}


@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
    0% {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: -30px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 75px;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 20px 35px rgba(20,20,20,.1);
 border-radius: 30px / 40px;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    50% {
 bottom: 30px;
 margin-left: -10px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 5px;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 20px 35px rgba(20,20,20,.3);
 border-radius: 20px / 20px;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    100% {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: -30px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 75px;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 20px 35px rgba(20,20,20,.1);
 border-radius: 30px / 40px;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes shrink {
    0% {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: -30px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 75px;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 20px 35px rgba(20,20,20,.1);
 border-radius: 30px / 40px;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    50% {
 bottom: 30px;
 margin-left: -10px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 5px;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 20px 35px rgba(20,20,20,.3);
 border-radius: 20px / 20px;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    100% {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: -30px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 75px;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 20px 35px rgba(20,20,20,.1);
 border-radius: 30px / 40px;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball-wrapper">
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="ball-shadow"></div>
</div>
```